# How to fix "ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate" error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, computer-vision

Following up from here: [Calculating percentage of Bounding box overlap, for image detector evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349178/calculating-percentage-of-bounding-box-overlap-for-image-detector-evaluation/26386665#26386665), I'm getting an error at this line:

```
poly_clipped = poly.clip_to_bbox(clip_rect).to_polygons()[0]
```

This is the error:

```
 File "C:\work_asaaki\code\detection.py", line 32, in clip_boxes
    poly_clipped = poly.clip_to_bbox(clip_rect).to_polygons()[0]
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 909, in clip_to_bbox
    return self.make_compound_path(*paths)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 328, in make_compound_path
    vertices = np.vstack([x.vertices for x in args])
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 228, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

This doesn't always happen, it happens based on specific sets of polygons... What I'm trying to understand is when exactly does it not work? And how can I solve the issue?

Comment: it probably means that `tup` is empty. (Unfortunately I have no time to look at the code in detail)

Comment: You were right... if you add that as an answer, I'll select it. In the end I used try and was able to deal with the exception when the output is None.

Comment: All I did was look at the error message and guess at why `concatenate` raised. `tup` is a variable internal to numpy, so the problem cannot be solved there, it must be solved at the level of your script, which I don't have access to. So it would probably be better if you answered your own question and detailed what you changed before the function call to `clip_to_bbox`.