# How to check if rectangles overlap?

Tags: python

I have an array. e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

arr = []

arr.append(
([0.195, 0.229], [0.673, 0.754])
)

arr.append(
([1.0, 1.903], [0.161, 0.303])
)

arr.append(
([0.052, 0.321], [1.0, 1.929])
)
```

Each tuple in arr represents the `min_X, max_X, min_Y, max_Y` of a rectangle in an image (example resolution: 1280x1080):

```
return np.array([min_X, max_X]), np.array([min_Y, max_Y])
```

How can I check to see if any of the ROI's overlap?

Comment: How about constructing polygons with those coordinates and using [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/index.html) to check for overlap? See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/294206) on how to construct a polygon and [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html) for a guide on how to intersect polygons. Should be relatively efficient too.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look at other questions (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57247833/7212665?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if two rectangles overlap each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other)