# How do I match similar bounding boxes that are in two separate lists?

Tags: python, ocr, bounding-box

I have two lists of bounding boxes. One list is the expected location of the bounding boxes, and the second list is the value of the bounding boxes that are returned by an OCR program. The bounding box lists (below) are in the format of [Top, Left, Width, Height]

```
Expected_Boxes= [[96, 752, 784, 172],
 [876, 754, 674, 174],
 [1536, 756, 620, 170],
 [2146, 754, 318, 176],
 [1136, 960, 66, 70],
 [1406, 928, 906, 112],
 [184, 1076, 60, 56],
 [442, 1192, 812, 132],
 [1710, 1232, 62, 54],
 [2012, 1228, 58, 58],
 [176, 1332, 1062, 128],
 [1302, 1334, 1128, 126],
 [128, 1526, 950, 106],
 [1098, 1532, 402, 98],
 [1534, 1538, 450, 88],
 [2010, 1512, 434, 110],
 [804, 1680, 62, 62],
 [992, 1684, 56, 60],
 [742, 1816, 62, 60],
 [1158, 1814, 64, 60],
 [100, 1994, 776, 102],
 [910, 1996, 748, 98],
 [1728, 1994, 714, 96],
 [1728, 1994, 714, 96],
 [2218, 2302, 58, 62],
 [2072, 2486, 60, 60],
 [2218, 2486, 60, 62],
 [56, 1430, 336, 66]]

OCR_Boxes = [[793, 1660, 248, 81],
 [806, 223, 215, 85],
 [812, 1009, 219, 67],
 [812, 2248, 86, 53],
 [947, 1563, 556, 80],
 [970, 1143, 44, 44],
 [1080, 188, 46, 46],
 [1208, 651, 406, 82],
 [1234, 2015, 47, 46],
 [1235, 1710, 46, 47],
 [1364, 1422, 827, 96],
 [1375, 338, 602, 93],
 [1536, 1523, 516, 102],
 [1550, 2115, 180, 76],
 [1562, 429, 648, 70],
 [1691, 991, 48, 47],
 [1692, 808, 47, 46],
 [1822, 1765, 46, 48],
 [1823, 1166, 47, 47],
 [1824, 746, 46, 45],
 [2007, 195, 374, 91],
 [2011, 1858, 380, 82],
 [2014, 1019, 339, 81],
 [2304, 2223, 49, 50],
 [2305, 2078, 47, 46],
 [2492, 2224, 46, 47],
 [2492, 2081, 46, 47],
 [2553, 485, 1124, 48],
 [2790, 1168, 1269, 210],
 [2906, 193, 391, 89]]
```

As you can tell, the expected list might have more or less than the OCR list, and the values will not be the same. I attempted to solve this by using the following code:

```
def intersection_over_union(boxA, boxB):
    # determine the (x, y)-coordinates of the intersection rectangle
    xA = max(boxA[0], boxB[0])
    yA = max(boxA[1], boxB[1])
    xB = min(boxA[2], boxB[2])
    yB = min(boxA[3], boxB[3])
    # compute the area of intersection rectangle
    interArea = max(0, xB - xA + 1) * max(0, yB - yA + 1)
    # compute the area of both the prediction and ground-truth
    # rectangles
    boxAArea = (boxA[2] - boxA[0] + 1) * (boxA[3] - boxA[1] + 1)
    boxBArea = (boxB[2] - boxB[0] + 1) * (boxB[3] - boxB[1] + 1)
    # compute the intersection over union by taking the intersection
    # area and dividing it by the sum of prediction + ground-truth
    # areas - the interesection area
    iou = interArea / float(boxAArea + boxBArea - interArea)
    # return the intersection over union value
    return iou 



def match_bounding_boxes(image1, image2):
    matches = []
    for box1 in image1:
        best_iou = 0
        best_box = None
        for box2 in image2:
            iou = intersection_over_union(box1, box2)
            if iou > best_iou:
                best_iou = iou
                best_box = box2
        matches.append((box1, best_box))
    return matches
```

However, all matches return "None"... meaning something is logically wrong with the code. Can anyone spot it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating percentage of Bounding box overlap, for image detector evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349178/calculating-percentage-of-bounding-box-overlap-for-image-detector-evaluation)