# How can I determine that which rectangles has max overlap with given rectangle?

Tags: java, android, math

I'm working on finding maximum overlap rectangle.

I've tried using following lines of code but it returns with that rectangle is overlaping to other or not

```
public boolean isOverlapping(Rect r1, Rect r2) {
       if (r1.top < r2.top || r1.left > r2.left) {
           return false;
       }
       if (r1.width() < r2.width() || r1.height() > r2.height()) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
```

I expect output that rectangle 3 is most overlaping to given rectangle. Not list or number of rectangles that overlaping to given rectangle.

Comment: see `android.graphics.Rect` documentation

Comment: already checked for the same but can't find any useful method @pskink

Comment: so find `intersect`

Comment: already done with this `public static boolean isCollisionDetected(Rect v1, Rect v2) {
        return Rect.intersects(v1, v2);
    }` but it not returns expected output

Comment: have you read `Rect#intersect` documentation? if so, what is not clear?

Comment: it will return only that Rectangle 2 is overlapping to Rectangle 1 or not, and in my case I'm having list of rectangles so It'll return all overlapping rectangles, but I want only the maximum overlapping rectangle

Comment: so you have to iterate over your list and find the maximum

Comment: I'm just stucked at find maximum from that list

Comment: post your code then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of pseudo code to get you going:

```
for each rect in Rectangle list
  overlap = compuateOverlap(rect, givenRect)
```

In other words: it is relatively easy to actually **compute** the overlap area for two rectangles. Just do that, and compare the results, and isolate the maximum.

In case you need more guidance how to compute that overlap, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244686/1531124) for some inspiration.

Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9325084/1531124), there you find even the exact formula to use to compute the overlap area of two rectangles!

Comment: @DharmeshPrajapati Thanks for the comeback. And please consider to delete no longer required comments, so that future readers can focus on the technical content ;-)